# How to write multiple content into text file

Tags: c#, winforms, io

I have a text file but I don't know how I can insert more than one item on it...
This is my code:

```
    string path = @"data.txt";
    private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);          
    sw.Write(textBox1.Text);
    textBox1.Clear();
    sw.Close();
}
```

It only writes one time to the file, so If I type "Hi" and click the button it sends "Hi" to the file but if I type again on the texbox and click the button again it sends the new text and clears the other but I want to be adding multiple data not only 1 thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of [`Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=net-6.0) use [`AppendAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=net-6.0), which will also get you rid of the StreamWriter.

```
string path = @"data.txt";
private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.AppendAllText(path, textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine);
    textBox1.Clear();
}
```

It's very convenient because

> If the file does not exist, this method creates a file

Comment: And how could I break that into lines, like every new textbox item a new line

Comment: @PerkZz: changed the code to add a newline